# Show there exists a straight line through $(m,f(m)$ which lies below a convex function everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex and given some $m \in \mathbb{R} \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } f(m)=am+b \text{ and } ax+b \le f(x) \forall x$.

That is, there is a straight line through $(m,f(m))$ which lies below the function everywhere.
I want to do this starting only from the following definition of convexity, and without assuming differentiability:
$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in [0,1]$ have $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$

I can clearly see why this is the case from looking at a picture of a convex function (just take the tangent) but I don't see how to formalise this and without assuming differentiability. I've tried fiddling with the inequality provided by the definition of convexity, but my choices of $a$ and $b$ are always dependent on the value of $x$ I am considering.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat lengthy if you want to prove using only the definition.

Hint: Verify using definition that $\frac { f(m+h)-f(m)} h \leq \frac { f(m+k)-f(m)} k$ for $h <k$. Conclude that the right-hand derivative $f'(m+)$ of $f$ at $m$ exists and the line through $(m, f(m))$ with slope $f'(m+)$ lies below the curve. (You may also use left-hand deriavtive).